# Want to make an empty <div> element clickable via JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make two empty `<div>` elements clickable through the use of HTML and Javascript alone. No jQuery.
I have this HTML document...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>whatever</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_squares" media="screen" >
   <script src="lala.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Clickable Squares</h1>

   <div id="top_square" onclick="alert('Top square clicked')">
   </div>

   <div id="bottom_square">
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and also have this simple CSS...

```
#top_square {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #01FF55;  
}

#bottom_square {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #AB877F;
}
```

I want to make both squares create an alert box when clicked. The top square already achieves this through the HTML code, but I am unable to get the bottom
square to create a similar alert through Javascript code.
This is what I have tried...

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
   alert("you have successfully loaded an external .js file.");
   // this is just to check that lala.js is loading.

   var bottom_sqr = getElementById("bottom_square");
                   // I also tried calling 'document.getElementById'...

   bottom_sqr.onclick = handle_bottom_click;

   function handle_bottom_click() {
      alert('Bottom square clicked');
   }
```

This is not working at all... hence the post obviously.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing bracket on your init method and yes, `document` is required there. `window` is javascript's global object and no method `window.getElementById` exists:

```
function init() {
    alert("you have successfully loaded an external .js file.");
    // this is just to check that lala.js is loading.

    var bottom_sqr = document.getElementById("bottom_square"); // document is required here

    bottom_sqr.addEventListener('click', handle_bottom_click);

    function handle_bottom_click() {
        alert('Bottom square clicked');
    }
}
```

Since an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) isn't "clickable" by default, you need to attach an event listener with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of just `element.onclick`.

Edit: Apparently `element.onclick` is valid as `onclick` is a [global event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers).

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
var v = document.getElementById("bottom_square");
v.onclick = function(){
    alert("Bottom square clicked");
};
```

JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/41Ljp1w7/

The problem in your code is aside from missing closing bracket in init method and document selector, you are calling functions without using first brackets i.e. "window.onload = init;" instead of "window.onload = init()"

Comment: `window.onload = init()` will call the return value of `init` on page load instead of correctly calling `init` on page load.

Comment: Yes. That was the first teething problem I ran into when trying to get this to work. Thanks for quick response btw. All is good now!

Comment: window.onload = init();